# Using of Calc() function in css for padding left and top only

Tags: html, css, sass, bootstrap-4

I am designing a website in HTML & SASS. I have a fixed header & aside.

```
    header{
        width: 100%;
        box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 5;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
    aside{
        height: 100vh;
        width: 320px;
        border-right: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0 1.25rem;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        flex-direction: column;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        justify-content: center;
        z-index: 3;
    }
    main {
        padding: 69px 0 0 320px;
        z-index: 1;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

The main content is not taking the full width of the page. so how can I use calc() in main to minus the padding top & left from the width.[Here is the screenshot for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cK7yL.png)

Comment: box-sizing:border-box to your element

Comment: provide a screenshot of your problem

Comment: @sarif warsi Added the screenshot kindly check

Comment: Box-sizing: border-box has been added to the *{ box-szing: border-box;}...do I need to add it in main tag also?

Answer (score 0):

Try width: calc(100% - 320px);